# Jenkins Git Set up fail

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I get the connection error when I try to set up the connection:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h git@(IP address here):external-web/collette-com.git HEAD
```

I saw other similar problems and they figure out that I need to go to manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Git -> Path to Git executable, but there is no "Git" option in my configuration. I only have "GitHub" ,"GitHub Enterprise Servers", "Git plugin".. I am very confused and need help..

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have git installed on the system you're working on? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Yes. I just install the Git and it doesn't seem to work.. I am going to try restart the jenkins to see.

Comment: you need edit .ssh/config of jenkins user(usually it is /home/jenkins/.ssh/config) to add a host  section for your git server. additionally, a ssh key pair should be created for jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by restarting the Jenkins, I think Jenkins can only recognize the new system variable after restarting.